# Generate varying editboxes and textboxes based on number of blobs in image in Matlab GUI and write values in those

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I did image processing to detect white color in an image and after that I found out centroids of all blobs in image. Now, I am trying to develop a GUI in matlab in which I have to show centroids. For this I need edit boxes and text boxes in which I update my centroids values. Now, the problem is that in image, number of blobs are not fixed. This may be 0 or greater than 8 or 10 too. So, I want to change the number of boxes acc. to number of blobs. For example: Let case 1, in which I have three blobs in image so, there should be three rows of edit boxes in which every row have 2 edit boxes for x and y centroids. Let case 2, in which I have five blobs in image so, there should be five rows of edit boxes in which every row have 2 edit boxes for x and y centroids. I have wrote code to add edit and text boxes as shown in fig.

[image]

Code for this is as below:

```
function draw_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to draw (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
x= 150; y = 327; h = 136; w= 39; x1 = 349; y1= 327; h1= 101; w1= 39;
num = str2num(char(get(handles.edit1,'String')));
for i = 1:num
txt(i) = uicontrol('Style','text',...
        'Position',[x y-50*i h w],...
        'String',i);
edit(i) = uicontrol('Style','edit',...
        'Position',[x1 y1-50*i h1 w1],...
        'String',0);
edit(i) = uicontrol('Style','edit',...
        'Position',[x1+140 y1-50*i h1 w1],...
        'String',0);
      end
```

**But my problem is that I am unable to insert values in these edit boxes.** For example if for two blobs in image, centroids values be (100,200) and (260,122). So I have to put these values into respective edit boxes.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the handles to the edit boxes within the `handles` data structure so that you can access them from within another callback function

```
function draw_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    x= 150; y = 327; h = 136; w= 39; x1 = 349; y1= 327; h1= 101; w1= 39;
    num = str2num(char(get(handles.edit1,'String')));
    for i = 1:num
        txt(i) = uicontrol('Style','text',...
                'Position',[x y-50*i h w],...
                'String',i);
        editx(i) = uicontrol('Style','edit',...
                'Position',[x1 y1-50*i h1 w1],...
                'String',0);
        edity(i) = uicontrol('Style','edit',...
                'Position',[x1+140 y1-50*i h1 w1],...
                'String',0);
    end

    handles.txt = txt;
    handles.editx = editx;
    handles.edity = edity;

    % Store the handle structure
    guidata(hObject, handles);
```

And then you can update them from another callback

```
function other_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    set(handles.editx(1), 'String', 'x1');
    set(handles.edity(1), 'String', 'y1');
end
```

A better option in my opinion for displaying the centroid information is to use a [`uitable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html) where each centroid is a row. Then you don't have to constantly create new `uicontrol` objects

```
htable = uitable();

% Then from anywhere in your code
set(htable, 'Data', {1, 2; 3, 4; 5, 6; 7, 8}, 'ColumnName', {'X', 'Y'})
```